# Mule modularising/invoking private and sub flows

Tags: mule

I am modularising my mule configuration into multiple private and sub flows for common tasks such as a common notification/logging flow for example.

These flows require multiple different pieces of information in order to be invoked from various different flows.

What is the best practice to pass this information to the private/sub modularised flow?

Is it flow variables? session variables? create a map of these values as the payload?

I am currently using flow variables, but this makes the configuration very verbose.

Taking my logging flow as an example, I have multiple set-variable processors followed a flow-ref multiple times:

```
    <set-variable variableName="loggingEndpoint" value="xx" />
    <set-variable variableName="loggingPriority" value="INFO" />
    <set-variable variableName="loggingSubject"
        value="xxx" />
    <set-variable variableName="loggingBody"
        value="xxxxx" />
    <set-variable variableName="loggingCC"
                    value="xx" />

<flow-ref name="LoggingService" doc:name="Logging service" />
```

I do this multiple times so theres a lot of XML. But if flowVars is the best way to pass info to a private flow then I don't mind. Just want to know best practice.

Answer (score 0):

For logging purposes I would use a logging interceptor, as explained here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Interceptors
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Java+Component+Reference

If you have something more general, like sending an email or persisting info in a database you can put a  and send information in session variables. This way those time consuming tasks do not block your main flow.

Regards.